# VSTO: How to add text after a bookmark in Word with different formating within the text

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I have a word document with a bookmark. I use the bookmark to get a range object which I then set the text of and add to the document. Now I want to add text after that newly added text but with different formatting how do I do this? Now I use something like

```
object oRangeStart = (object) previousRange.End + 1;
object oRangeEnd = (object) previousRange.End + 2;
Word.Range newRange = doc.Range(ref oRangeStart, ref oRangeEnd);
newRange.Text = "Hello, world!";
```

and then insert it but it shows up at the wrong place.

The reason I can't use one single range is that I want to insert something like

**Name**

Lorem ipsum. *$99.99*

and I believe I need a different range object for each style I want to apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically use range to swap out text when needed. Try using Application.Selection:

```
Word.Selection curSel = Application.Selection;
curSel.TypeText("Type Some Text");
```

In your case, try this:

```
Word.Selection curSel;
int endOfRange =  previousRange.End + 1;
curSel.SetRange(endOfRange, endOfRange);

curSel.Font.Bold = 1;
curSel.TypeText("Hello, world!");
curSel.Font.Bold = 0;
curSel.TypeParagraph();
```